# Remember paging number in CMS system

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have this site link:
http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/index/page/1

It holds a ton of news articles so I've integrated a paginator. When you click e.g. '4' in the paginator: the link will change to:

http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/index/page/4

When a user clicks a random news article on page 4, the link will change to:

http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/55/edit

But then I have a 'back button' that should link to

http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/index/page/4

instead of the very first paginator element

(http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/index/page/1).

What's the best practice with this?

- Using cookies to remember the pagination number
- Using sessions to remember the pagination number
- Insert the pagination number into the detail page link (e.g. http://my-site.com/admin/news_articles/55/edit/take-me-back-to-pagination/4)

Thanks for giving you opinion on this one!

Grtz,
Sam

Comment: The right approach would be to make sure that a clicked link is added to the browser's history (which it should do normally). So the question is _how_ you link to article on page 4 and why this isn't added to the history.

Comment: What do you mean with 'added to the browser's history'? I want to be as user-friendly as possible and offer the user a back-button apart from the back-button of the browser or a javascript 'history-back' button ;)

Comment: To make the browser navigate to the right page when hitting the "back" button, the right page needs to be in the browser's history. A normal link, a form, all normal stuff will do that automaticly. A javascript location change _might not_ do that. This is why I asked _how_ you do _"When you click e.g. '4' in the paginator: the link will change to"_. Without knowing that we can only guess.